# How to draw a regular rounded-corners hexagons with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following picture, which is six regular rounded-corners hexagons, ring, circles and labels.

[image: six regular rounded-corners hexagons, ring circles and labels]

Comment: Welcome. // What did you try?

Comment: There is a nice [online manual to Ti*k*Z](https://tikz.dev), where you will find instructions how to use the `rounded corners` option.

Comment: @MS-SPO I can draw a single one regular rounded-corner hexagon (code below). I am trying my best in order to draw more than one regular rounded-corners hexagons together, like the ones in posted picture.  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rounded corners, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=2.7cm
    ] (hexagon) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Ok, just complete your code and EDIT it to your question, e.g. this way: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: Basically, you need to add `at (x,y)` to each node for different x,y locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `path picture` you can create your hex nodes with the circles inside.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    myhex/.style={draw, thick, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=4cm, rounded corners, path picture={\fill(path picture bounding box) circle[radius=1.25cm];}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill circle[radius=2cm];
\draw[white, line width=2pt] circle[radius=1.5cm];
\foreach \t[count=\n] in {30,90,...,330}{\node[myhex](H\n) at (\t:4){};}
\foreach \t[evaluate=\t as \s using {int(1+mod(\t,6))}, evaluate=\t as \r using {int(1+mod(\t,6))}, evaluate=\t as \q using {int(1+mod(\r+3,6))}] in {1,...,6}{\draw[thick] (H\t.corner \r)to[bend left](H\s.corner \q);}
\foreach \t/\l in {0/label1,60/label2,120/label3,180/label4,240/label5,300/label6}{\node[rotate={\t+180*(and(\t>90,\t<270))}] at (\t:3.5){\l};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bigger hexagon as a frame.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,inner sep=2.5cm, rotate=30] (frame) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 1) {1};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 2) {2};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 3) {3};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 4) {4};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 5) {5};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw, inner sep=1cm] at (frame.corner 6) {6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]